# Classical notion of trajectory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, observables

1. Why the classical notion of trajectory is meaningless in quantum
   mechanics?

I am asking here about notion of trajectory from classical mechanics and why in quantum mechanics we cannot use it or is meaningless

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us some idea of what research you've done in this area. Your question is very broad and we would need it to be more precise before we can give a useful answer here.

Comment: @JohnRennie Seems clear to me: The OP has found a claim to this effect and did not understand its meaning, hence hoping for an answer here.

Comment: @JamesMatthews If you cannot elaborate in your own words, pointing to the source might help give people an idea how to answer without rewriting all of whatever book you took this statement from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classical mechanics, each body has an exact position at all times (and hence an exact speed given by its derivative, and the equivalent quantities for rotary motion). To understand the difference to quantum mechanics, think of it as wave mechanics: Each body is described by a wave(function) and properties such as position or speed are only defined to the extent that they can be defined for a wave: Not arbitrarily well, at least not all such quantities simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, and restricting to particles for now, a classical trajectory is a set of exact *positions* and corresponding *velocities* (or momenta) of the particle, which (usually) change over time. In quantum mechanics, the uncertainty principle says that it is not possible to know *simultaneously* the exact position and momentum of the particle, and so it becomes harder (and I suppose eventually meaningless) to define a trajectory for a quantum system.